# Does Unity3D supports different pixel densities like native android?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

Native android supports different pixel densities like ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and so on. This feature balances app quality and app size.

Currently I'm facing this issue in Unity mobile games (iOS & android) when I use,

- high quality graphics it increases crashes and lagging in low-end devices.
- low quality graphics it looks blurry and pixelated in high-end devices like iPad Pro etc.

I can use 2 different quality images but again it increases app size as the low-end devices end up downloading the HD images too.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: We have good experiences with the official Unity [Vector Graphics](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.vectorgraphics@2.0/manual/index.html) Package, we you can use an SVG. It requires Anti Aliasing and not everything is supported, but other than those, it works great.

Comment: @JeanLuc I have also tried SVG images but a single SVG [image](https://imgur.com/gcBIb8L.png) has more than 4000+ vertices and I had a scene with 200+ images, so it crashed in low-end devices. I used Adobe Animate to create these SVG images. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at the Unity Addressables system available in Unity 2020 LTS and beyond. This is a whole new tool that you'll have to investigate so I cannot provide a quick class or line of code to solve your problem. However, the Unity Addressables system is available in the Package Manager with docs available [here.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@1.19/manual/index.html)

Using this system will likely make it easier to run hi-res assets on lower-end devices. Since assets are streamed in when needed your texture memory is going to be significantly reduced as textures are unloaded as soon as you're done with them.

Addressables can also be used to load in assets remotely which would reduce your total file size. However, depending on how far you are in development this could be a big change.

You may also want to look at splitting the application binary if changing over to Addressables is too much work. If you split the binary, you can reduce the initial download of the application and have users opt-in to hi-res textures. There are a variety of other solutions provided by the Unity docs on Android builds [here.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-BuildProcess.html#splitting-apks)

Good luck on getting your game to a shipped state!